# How to manipulate divs to render only a few at a time without lag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a "unique enough" question, but I've found it to be too specific to find it already answered. I'm attempting to dynamically create a map with block-display-styled divs using JavaScript. To prevent lag, I just want the elements to be created and destroyed as the user "moves the camera" which is really just moving everything one space to any direction, and deleting the row/column that is not visible anymore.

Thus, I have two constructs, one which is data-only, the array that stores the whole map, and another one which represents the plane only the user can see, and is made up of divs.

The problem comes when the map is initially rendered, since the first visible element is NOT the first square of the actual map, but actually an area inside that shares the same middle. See the following image for reference:

[image: visual representation of map]

```
for (var n = 0 ; n < map_xy.lenght; n++){ // Will repeat by the number of cells
    var newtile = document.createElement('div');
    newtile.className = "map_cell";
    newtile.id = n.toString();
};
```

**My Question is: How can I make it so that the program knows about the whole map without actually rendering it?**. This is something I need, there will be terrain generation that will search for adjacent cells and other similar things.

I don't even know if this is the correct aproach, my goal is to reduce lag as much as posible, so that when a user requests a 1000 by 1000 cell map, he/she can still only see his/her 40~ by 40~ "window", so that the browser won't just crash.

Thanks for your help, I'll edit this if it's unclear in its current state.

Comment: You can look up how virtual lists are done.  The cells of the entire map are stored as Javascript objects with position information (where they appear), perhaps as an array.  You then need to calculate the visible window and determine which cells are within that window (plus some buffer so that scrolling is still smooth).  Then you update the DOM to only render those cells.  You might want to look up virtual DOM implementations as well to improve the performance of the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close. I would use a 2-dimensional array to store the whole map, in which case you can use nested loops with pre-defined boundaries on the initial rendering.

```
var map; // assume this is a 2D array, where each element has a property 
         //called "tileID", which you want assigned to a corresponding div
for(var x = init_x_left; x < init_x_right; x++){
    for(var y = init_y_top; y < init_y_bot; y++){
        var newtile = document.createElement('div');
        newtile.className = "map_cell";
        newtile.id = map[x][y].tileID; // example
    }
}
```

Where `init_x_left`, `init_x_right`, `init_y_top`, `init_y_top`, enclose the initial area that you want rendered.

The important thing to note here is that the code you posted starts at `0` and goes until `map_xy.length`, which will make the entire map render every time because you are traversing the whole array. On top of that, you're storing 2D information in a 1D array, and that makes working with that information more complicated than it needs to be, in my opinion, though I suppose it's not impossible?

However, after searching a bit, it doesn't seem like javascript has an easy way of declaring a 2D array, so you would have to write a function to generate and populate one.

Bill mentioned in a comment about virtual lists/DOM, which if done well is probably a more elegant solution than this one, but would present its own challenges as well. If there was a way to find out how Google Maps scrolls seamlessly, I would try to replicate that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual answer, but it does illustrate why the problem exists:

https://jsfiddle.net/atrpm1qy/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            overflow: scroll;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .row {
            white-space: nowrap;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-size: 0;
        }

        .tile {
            display: inline-block;
            background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
            height: 32px;
            width: 32px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        var rows = 100;
        var columns = 100;

        var map = document.querySelector('#map');
        var row, column, tileRow, tile;
        var height = 0;
        var width = 0;

        function makeRow() {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.classList.add("row");
            return div;
        }

        function makeTile() {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.classList.add("tile");
            return div;
        }

        for (row = 0; row < rows; row += 1) {
            tileRow = makeRow();
            map.appendChild(tileRow);
            width = 0;
            for (column = 0; column < columns; column += 1) {
                tile = makeTile();
                tileRow.appendChild(tile);
                width += tile.offsetWidth;

            }
            height += tileRow.offsetHeight;
        }

        map.scrollTop = height / 2 - map.offsetWidth / 2;
        map.scrollLeft = width / 2 - map.offsetHeight / 2;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Get up to very many tiles and the browser gets mighty angry.

I'd probably explore the Canvas tag to draw the map.